# Can't log in to other users on a debian system

Tags: debian, users, login, password, passwd

I can't **log in** to `KDE`, as other users to the GUI on my `Debian` systems only the user created at install.

I can log on in the command line:

```
su - user
```

into the users login but only in the shell.

I have created a login shell

```
usermod -s /bin/bash user
```

and deleted users and created new ones

```
useradd -m user
```

I've tried to change the password:

```
sudo passwd user
```

---

```
cat /etc/passwd   # gives

Óuser:x:1001:1001::/home/Óuser:/bin/bash
```

os-release:

```
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"
```

When I try to login I get `login failed` like when you have a wrong password but I'm sure I have the right passwords.

Comment: Is the `Ó` character part of the username? What command _exactly_ did you use when you created the user and did you use any non-ascii characters in the username? (please include the actual username).

Comment: @Kusalananda yes it's part username=Óli

Comment: @Kusalananda If a question deserves a answer, I would also think it deserves atleast one up vote, this is so stupid

Comment: An oversight on my part. Corrected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usernames on Debian systems must start with an ASCII letter or underscore, and then only contain letters, digits, dashes or underscores. The username may end with an optional `$`. The maximum length is 32 characters.

Instead of `Óli`, I would suggest `oli` and then to set the user's "real name" to `Óli`.

See also: [What is the regex to validate Linux users?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157426/what-is-the-regex-to-validate-linux-users)

Comment: That did the trick