# How to get ldap/nss/pam to accept usernames beginning with a number: pam_systemd(gdm-password:session): Failed to get user record: Invalid argument

Tags: pam, openldap, nss

How to get my ldap/pam/nss stack to accept usernames beginning with a number?

I am installing LDAP/NSS/PAM with [the instructions provided by debian](https://wiki.debian.org/LDAP/NSS#NSS_Setup_with_libnss-ldapd).  I have tried both `libnss-ldap`, and `libnss-ldapd`

They both work...as long as a user's username does not start with a number (or in libnss-ldap case, usernames also can't have a period in them).  Unfortunately, all of the usernames in my organization are seven digit numbers!

Here is the error when trying to log in with username `9999999`:

```
...gdm-password][5010]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user 9999999 by (uid=0)
...gdm-password][5010]: pam_systemd(gdm-password:session): Failed to get user record: Invalid argument
```

Where as here are the same logs when trying to log in with the username `test`

```
...gdm-password][5242]: pam_unix(gdm-password:session): session opened for user test by (uid=0)
```

I am using the version of the libnss-ldap package that is installed with Ubuntu 20.04, which is [version 0.9.11-1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/libnss-ldapd)

Comment: Thank you! After hours of investigating this issue on my site, your question pointed me in the right direction. Apparently some tools, when presented a digit-only username, mistake it for a UID. In fact, digit-only usernames are [frowned](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/157426/) [upon](https://serverfault.com/questions/73084/) in Linux. Anecdotal evidence suggests one can get away with them if the username matches the UID, but I could not try that. At least the [coreutils](https://github.com/coreutils/gnulib/blob/master/lib/userspec.c#L170) do parse the username to int.